# Azure Functions Custom ILogger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

Hopefully some people with a much better understanding of Azure Functions than i do can help.

Out of the box, you can log to Application Insights by using the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY setting in your app settings... this will log, at a basic level the Function requests, and then allow you to do `log.LogInformation` etc.

This is simply covered off by either a TraceWriter, or ILogger.

Issue is though, i don't want to store the Key in my config, i want to store it in KeyVault, along with all other keys for the App. I also want to do some other custom logging, so as per this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-in-c-functions
We can implement a custom `TelemetryClient()` object to read from KeyVault without much hassle..

However, all the nice free logging you get by using ILogger is now gone, so i guess what i need to do is somehow inject an Application Insights ILogger into my Function...

Can someone help me understand the limitations here, as in how it *would* be done if it were possible.. i also assume there must be a GitHub open case for it which i would be keen on finding, and lending weight to as i can't imagine I'm the only one that has faced this.

Answer (score 0):

> Issue is though, i don't want to store the Key in my config, i want to store it in KeyVault, along with all other keys for the App.

We could store the ***APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY*** in the Key Vault. I recommand the you could use the [Azure MSI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/) function .

I also do a demo for it. The following is my detail steps.

1.Create an azure function app and enable the MSI  from azure portal

[image]

2.Create an Application Insight application and copy the INSTRUMENTATIONKEY value.

[image]

3.Create a secret with copied INSTRUMENTATIONKEY vaule.

[image]

4.If want to get the secret from the Azure application we need to add the access policy

[image]

5.Create a httptrigger function with VS and add the following demo code.

```
 public static async Task<TelemetryClient> GeTelemetryClient()
        {
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

            var keyVaultClient =
                new KeyVaultClient(
                    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

            var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://{keyvault}.vault.azure.net/secrets/{sceret}")
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new TelemetryClient {InstrumentationKey = secret.Value};
        }

        // This correllates all telemetry with the current Function invocation
        private static void UpdateTelemetryContext(TelemetryContext context, ExecutionContext functionContext,
            string userName)
        {
            context.Operation.Id = functionContext.InvocationId.ToString();
            context.Operation.ParentId = functionContext.InvocationId.ToString();
            context.Operation.Name = functionContext.FunctionName;
            context.User.Id = userName;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]

        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
            ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            // Get request body
            dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

            // Set name to query string or body data
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            // Track an Event
            var telemetryClient = await GeTelemetryClient().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var evt = new EventTelemetry("Function called");
            UpdateTelemetryContext(evt.Context, context, name);

            telemetryClient.TrackEvent(evt);

            // Track a Metric
            var metric = new MetricTelemetry("Test Metric", DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            UpdateTelemetryContext(metric.Context, context, name);
            telemetryClient.TrackMetric(metric);

            // Track a Dependency
            var dependency = new DependencyTelemetry
            {
                Name = "GET api/planets/1/",
                Target = "swapi.co",
                Data = "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
                Timestamp = start,
                Duration = DateTime.UtcNow - start,
                Success = true
            };
            UpdateTelemetryContext(dependency.Context, context, name);
            telemetryClient.TrackDependency(dependency);

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

6.Publish the project to azure, and test it from the azure

[image]

7.Check the from the Application Insight.

[image]